# Identifying clickable area

Tags: jquery

I have a div class="parent" . When I click on it I need to clone div class="child" and show them depending on the parent area I clicked.  The problem arises when I click on the div class="child", another child div appears which is the behavior I don't really want.
One way to overcome this trouble is to write something like this:

`$('.parent').click(function(event){
   if (event.target.className != 'child'){
       $('.child').clone().show();
    }
 });`

I consider that this is not very elegant as, if inside of div class="child" would be children, then you have to put them in the if() statement also.
Could someone tell me how to manage this problem. Probably there is a way to put all children of the div class="child" in an array and to loop over them.
Any ideas and thoughts appreciated,
Thanks

Comment: you need to post your html too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.parent').click(function(event){ 
  if (event.target === this){
     $('.child').clone().show();
  }
});
```

Should only target parent and not the children. From the jQuery docs:

> **event.target:**
>   The target property can be the element
>   that registered for the event or a
>   descendant of it. It is often useful
>   to compare event.target to this in
>   order to determine if the event is
>   being handled due to event bubbling.
>   This property is very useful in event
>   delegation, when events bubble.

[Source](http://api.jquery.com/event.target/)

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong with this?

```
$('.parent').click( function(e) {
  $(this).find('div[class=child]').show();
});
```

Comment: when you click on a child div another child div will show which is the behavior I don't want

Comment: I need several child divs to show inside of parent div and I need to show them when parent area is clicked, but they also appear when a child area is clicked and I don't want that

Answer (score 1):

try

```
jQuery('.parent').bind('click', function(){
    var NewChild = jQuery('.child').clone(false);
    NewChild.appendTo(jQuery(this));
    NewChild.show();
}
```

this clones the child and appends it to your parent, i dont know if this is needed if not just remove the appendTo and set clone(true)

Comment: The problem is when you click on a .child div another .child div will appear.

Comment: I only need to clone and show child div if the clickable area eqals to parent div but not child div